# Error about static local functions after adding a method

Tags: c#, function, error-handling

I have just started C# and I'm using functions to start to set up a basic login system, however, when I set up a new function it gives me his error:

> Error CS8652  The feature 'static local functions' is currently in
>   Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview'
>   language version.

This is the code that is showing the problem:

```
using System;

namespace Sub_routines___Repetition_of_letter
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void homepage()
        {
            bool exit = false;
            while (exit == false)
            {
                // some code
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                homepage();
            }    
        }
    }    
}
```

The code error that I am told is that on line 82, which is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Comment: No, that code does not cause that compiler error. Read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: It look like you are using a web project.   So it appears you change something on the main form so homepage() type changes.   VS automatically crate the program.cs module when the project is crated and make a call from the module to you homepage.  Something you did on the homepage module cause the issue.

Comment: well, error is pretty self explanatory ... you cannot define static function(prolly `Main`) inside a method body

Comment: @jdweng please. Just don't.

Comment: The single snippets by themselves would not provide enough context about what is causing the problem. You are sure to get more help if you show the code as written so that those trying to help you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah so you've moved your `main` method into your `homepage` method as @Selvin guessed correctly. Move it out again by dragging, cut&paste or ending the `homepage()`  method with a `}` and removing the extraneous `}` at the end of your file.

Comment: @Nkosi it's open again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function outside inside the class but not inside another function.

This error is because you're incorrectly declaring your homepage() function from within another static method.

Could you post the declaration of your "Homepage()" method?

Comment: No, they're not. The code they show _calls_ a method, it doesn't declare it.

Comment: I'm thinking outside the box a little, if they aren't immediately getting a compiler error then that function must be declared somewhere, and that error suggests its defined within another function

Comment: Yes, a compiler returning an error usually means there's an error somewhere in the code. That doesn't mean you should post a blanket statement answer stating such; the OP must ask an answerable question.

Comment: If that is also declared within your Program.cs file, can you update the post with your full class? Would help give a little context to this error

Comment: @CodeCaster I would've asked in a comment if he could've posted the full code first, but I didn't have 50 rep, and didnt want to post an "answer" that wasnt an answer. On top of that, my answer isn't wrong, the poster doesn't understand the error, or why it's happening, I explained why it's happening

Comment: *Could you post the declaration of your "Homepage()" method?* irrelevant, I bet that `Main` is inside other method

Comment: @Selvin I hadn't thought about that, but yeah that could be it